# Leave Event being triggered on Mouse Click but not on directional keys

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have this screenshot from my application. To explain what is happening is that i am using the leave event to show a MessageBox when a valid item is not selected from the list. Currently it comes up if I start typing and then try to select the item with the mouse but doesnt come up if I use the arrow keys. For eg. in this screenshot where I type in "cen" and I want to select "Camp Chicken Broth 10.5oz (17960)" from the list, if I use the directional keys and then hit enter it is fine but if I use the mouse then the MessageBox below event is raised. I notice also that it allows selection by the left click of the mouse after the MessageBox has been closed. Selecting an item after the user closes the MessageBox is quite bothersome. Is there a work around for this? Below the image is the Leave Event function

[image]

```
private void suggestComboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox c_med = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (!suggestComboBox1.Items.Contains(c_med.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Cari-med Item!");
        }
    }
```

Updated with suggestComboBox

```
  using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoCompleteComboBox
{
public class SuggestComboBox : ComboBox
{
    #region fields and properties

    private readonly ListBox _suggLb = new ListBox { Visible = false, TabStop = false };
    private readonly BindingList<string> _suggBindingList = new BindingList<string>();
    private Expression<Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>>> _propertySelector;
    private Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>> _propertySelectorCompiled;
    private Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> _filterRule;
    private Func<string, bool> _filterRuleCompiled;
    private Expression<Func<string, string>> _suggestListOrderRule;
    private Func<string, string> _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled;

    public int SuggestBoxHeight
    {
        get { return _suggLb.Height; }
        set { if (value > 0) _suggLb.Height = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the item-type of the ComboBox is not string,
    /// you can set here which property should be used
    /// </summary>
    public Expression<Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>>> PropertySelector
    {
        get { return _propertySelector; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            _propertySelector = value;
            _propertySelectorCompiled = value.Compile();
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Lambda-Expression to determine the suggested items
    /// (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
    /// <para>default: case-insensitive contains search</para>
    /// <para>1st string: list item</para>
    /// <para>2nd string: typed text</para>
    ///</summary>
    public Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> FilterRule
    {
        get { return _filterRule; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            _filterRule = value;
            _filterRuleCompiled = item => value.Compile()(item, Text);
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Lambda-Expression to order the suggested items
    /// (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
    /// <para>default: alphabetic ordering</para>
    ///</summary>
    public Expression<Func<string, string>> SuggestListOrderRule
    {
        get { return _suggestListOrderRule; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            _suggestListOrderRule = value;
            _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = value.Compile();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// ctor
    /// </summary>
    public SuggestComboBox()
    {
        // set the standard rules:
        _filterRuleCompiled = s => s.ToLower().Contains(Text.Trim().ToLower());
        _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = s => s;
        _propertySelectorCompiled = collection => collection.Cast<string>();

        _suggLb.DataSource = _suggBindingList;
        _suggLb.Click += SuggLbOnClick;

        ParentChanged += OnParentChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the magic happens here ;-)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (!Focused) return;

        _suggBindingList.Clear();
        _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
        _propertySelectorCompiled(Items)
             .Where(_filterRuleCompiled)
             .OrderBy(_suggestListOrderRuleCompiled)
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(_suggBindingList.Add);
        _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        _suggBindingList.ResetBindings();

        _suggLb.Visible = _suggBindingList.Any();

        if (_suggBindingList.Count == 1 &&
                    _suggBindingList.Single().Length == Text.Trim().Length)
        {
            Text = _suggBindingList.Single();
            Select(0, Text.Length);
            _suggLb.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    #region size and position of suggest box

    /// <summary>
    /// suggest-ListBox is added to parent control
    /// (in ctor parent isn't already assigned)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent.Controls.Add(_suggLb);
        Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(_suggLb, 0);
        _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3;
        _suggLb.Left = Left + 3;
        _suggLb.Width = Width - 20;
        _suggLb.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9);
    }

    protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLocationChanged(e);
        _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3;
        _suggLb.Left = Left + 3;
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        _suggLb.Width = Width - 20;
    }

    #endregion

    #region visibility of suggest box

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        // _suggLb can only getting focused by clicking (because TabStop is off)
        // --> click-eventhandler 'SuggLbOnClick' is called
        if (!_suggLb.Focused)
            HideSuggBox();
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    private void SuggLbOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Text = _suggLb.Text;
        Focus();
    }

    private void HideSuggBox()
    {
        _suggLb.Visible = false;
    }

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        HideSuggBox();
        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }

    #endregion

    #region keystroke events

    /// <summary>
    /// if the suggest-ListBox is visible some keystrokes
    /// should behave in a custom way
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suggLb.Visible)
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            return;
        }

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Down:
                if (_suggLb.SelectedIndex < _suggBindingList.Count - 1)
                    _suggLb.SelectedIndex++;
                return;
            case Keys.Up:
                if (_suggLb.SelectedIndex > 0)
                    _suggLb.SelectedIndex--;
                return;
            case Keys.Enter:
                Text = _suggLb.Text;
                Select(0, Text.Length);
                _suggLb.Visible = false;
                return;
            case Keys.Escape:
                HideSuggBox();
                return;
        }

        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }

    private static readonly Keys[] KeysToHandle = new[] { Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Enter, Keys.Escape };
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        // the keysstrokes of our interest should not be processed be base class:
        if (_suggLb.Visible && KeysToHandle.Contains(keyData))
            return true;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Try TextChanged or SelectedValueChanged instead of Leave

Comment: But if I use those they won't do what I want though. I want it to raise the MessageBox when no match is found in the comboBox list of values @RobertoPegoraro

Comment: Are you using any more events besides Leave? Because I could not reproduce your error here

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro no no other events. I had a custom suggestComboBox .cs file and  am wondering if that is causing the issue. currently it handles `Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Enter, Keys.Escape` am wondering if not handling the mouse click could be the problem

Comment: Remove the custom suggestComboBox.cs file and try adding the suggestions directly in the properties panel in the AutoCompleteCustomSource and see if the error continues.

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro no it doesn't persist but this .cs file is needed as it enables me to can search by sub-string for the AutoComplete suggest option. Winforms doesn't support sub-string search. Only by first character in string it supports

Comment: Put the code of the suggestComboBox.cs class and how it is feeding the sugest of the combobox

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro just updated it

Comment: The problem is this code: base.OnLostFocus (e); It is calling the leave function and firing the event when clicking, the solution is to comment on that line and check what problems will occur, at first I did not find any problem.

Method: OnLostFocus on SuggestComboBox.cs

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro same issue even though I commented OnLostFocus

Comment: Try also comment Focus(); on SuggLbOnClick method

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro same result

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro I believe I have found the issue. Originally I created a comboBox through the designer view in winforms and now this .cs which is SuggestComboBox is calling a second comboBox within that first one as to facilitate the substring search. So basically it is a comboBox operating within another comboBox. Therefore each time I try to select from this new comboBox, it will always trigger the Leave Event of the first box because am accessing the 2nd comboBox and not the first. Now I have to find  a way to go around that because I want to do a check that values entered are in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I retraced my steps and everything and remembered I had changed my query and since then I started having the issue. Originally this was the function which populated the comboBox above with values:

```
 void fillCari()//fill Cari-med dropdown with values
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=CMDLAP126;Initial Catalog=Carimed_Inventory;User ID = sa; Password = 123456;";
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con2.Open();
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Item_Description FROM dbo.Carimed"; 
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("Item_Description"));
                suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des);
                suggestComboBox1.Text.Trim();
            }
            //con2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

This particular line was the issue:

```
   string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Item_Description FROM dbo.Carimed";
```

Turns out it has something to do with "DISTINCT." Am not entirely sure why removing it and changing it to this solved my issue:

```
   string query = "SELECT Item_Description FROM dbo.Carimed";
```